# Convert number to corresponding words

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to develop a piece of code that converts a number to the corresponding words, e.g. `1` -> `"One"`, `2` -> `"Two"`

Is there any function in Python to do this task?

Comment: No, there is no built-in function for this.

Comment: Hi jonrsharpe
thanks for you suggestions

Comment: http://pynum2word.sourceforge.net/ `num2word.to_card(1)` --> `one`.

Comment: use a dict with mapping `1:"One"` etc..

Comment: Use a list with the words in the corresponding index numbers (assuming they cannot be negative).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Convert numbers to Words in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19504350/how-to-convert-numbers-to-words-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this question is "no".  There is no function **in Python** to do this task.

---

If you "have to **develop code** to do it" (your words), then using a builtin wouldn't really be a valid solution, perhaps?

If you have to develop code to do it, you need better specifications.   Do you have to be able to just do 0..9, or any cardinal number, or any number at all? (floating point? decimal? negative?).   Why do you have to develop this code?  Is it homework, or some special purpose?

If you just have to do 0..9, then as mentioned in comments, you should use a dictionary.   Take care of case of the input.

If you have to do anything more than that, looking at the implementation of num2word would certainly be educational.

Comment: Hi GreenAsJade,

Thanks for valuable suggestion, I need to dispaly not only 0..9 but need to dispaly any numbers (floating point, decimal or negative).
I will certainly take help of num2word develop the same.

Thanks a lot

Comment: To encourage people to answer your questions, you should mark an answer as "accepted", by clicking the tick,  when you have accepted it's contents.   Note that you can change your mind later if a better answer comes along.  Good luck with num->word