# Short Form Number into Words Python

Tags: python, numbers, short

Looking for help in changing a number input and converting it to a short form word:

```
for instance 4,000,000,000 -> 4 Trillion, 
ones = ["", "one ","two ","three ","four ", "five ", "six ","seven ","eight ","nine "]
tens = ["ten ","eleven ","twelve ","thirteen ", "fourteen ", "fifteen ","sixteen ","seventeen ","eighteen ","nineteen "]
twenties = ["","","twenty ","thirty ","forty ", "fifty ","sixty ","seventy ","eighty ","ninety "]
thousands = ["","thousand ","million ", "billion ", "trillion ", "quadrillion ", "quintillion ", "sextillion ", "septillion ","octillion ", "nonillion ", "decillion ", "undecillion ", "duodecillion ", "tredecillion ", "quattuordecillion ", "quindecillion", "sexdecillion ", "septendecillion ",  "octodecillion ", "novemdecillion ", "vigintillion "]

def wordNumber(number):
    number = int(number)  

number = str(input("Enter the digits: "))    
print(wordNumber(number))
```

I am completely stumped on where to go next and I've looked at a lot of programs online that do the exact thing with full numbers (10)--> ten.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to do this manually, here is a partial example of one way to go about it.

```
def f(number):
    ones    =   [
                    "",
                    "one",
                    "two",
                    "three",
                    "four",
                    "five",
                    "six",
                    "seven",
                    "eight",
                    "nine",
                ]
    teens   =   {
                    10:"ten",
                    11:"eleven",
                    12:"twelve",
                    13:"thirteen",
                    14:"fourteen",
                    15:"fifteen",
                    16:"sixteen",
                    17:"seventeen",
                    18:"eighteen",
                    19:"nineteen",
                }
    tens    =   [
                    "",
                    "teen",
                    "twenty",
                    "thirty",
                    "fourty",
                    "fifty",
                    "sizty",
                    "seventy",
                    "eighty",
                    "ninety",
                ]
    hundred =   [ "%shundred" % one for one in ones ]
    place_value   = {1:ones,2:tens,3:hundred}
    number_string = ""
    number        = list(str(number))
    number.reverse()
    number        = [(place+1, int(digit)) for place, digit in enumerate(number)]
    number.reverse()
    number_iter = number.__iter__()
    for place, digit in number_iter:
        print place, digit
        if place == 2 and digit == 1:
            place, digit = number_iter.next()
            number_string += teens[10 + digit]
        else:
            number_string += place_value[place][digit]
        print number_string
```

Comment: This was the best code by far, but I had to go another route.   Would you please see my next post down?

Comment: I posted my  most recent code because I was having difficulty, here:  http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#togetherjs=Td1Iwzyix8

Answer (score 1):

The [Humanize](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/humanize) library will do that for you:

```
>>> humanize.intword(12345591313)
'12.3 billion'
```

Comment: never heard of the humanize library. Thanks. I will see if this can be imported.

Answer (score 0):

It's need a lot of code. You can do this like:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19506803/3260314

Or just use modules. Example: [num2words](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/num2words)

```
>>> from num2words import num2words
>>> num2words(42)
forty-two
>>> num2words(42, ordinal=True)
forty-second
>>> num2words(42, lang='fr')
quarante-deux
```

Comment: This could work but the problem with it is that num2words is not available in all instances of python.