# Convert Python integers to words

Tags: python

I wrote the following code that is suppose to convert all number from 1 to 9999 to words but I'm getting out of range for numbers like 111 etc. Pls help. Thanks.

```
global n2W
n2W = {1: 'one', 2: 'two', 3: 'three', 4: 'four', 5: 'five',\
        6: 'six', 7: 'seven', 8: 'eight', 9: 'nine', 10: 'ten', \
        11: 'eleven', 12: 'twelve', 13: 'thirteen', 14: 'fourteen', \
        15: 'fifteen', 16: 'sixteen', 17: 'seventeen', 18: 'eighteen',\
        19: 'nineteen',20:'twenty', 30:'thirty', 40:'forty', 50:'fifty', 60:'sixty',\
        70: 'seventy', 80:'eighty', 90:'ninety',100:'one hundred', 200:'two hundred',\
        300:'three hundred', 400:'four hundred',500:'five hundred', 600:'six hundred',\
        700:'seven hundred',800:'eight hundred', 900:'nine hundred',\
        1000:'one thousand', 2000:'two thousand', 3000:'three thousand',\
        5000:'five thousand', 6000:'six thousand', 7000:'seven thousand',\
        8000:'eight thousand', 9000:'nine thousand',10000:'ten thousand'}


def num2Word(n):
    try:
        print (n2W[n])
    except KeyError:

        try:
            print (n2W[n-n%10] , n2W[n%10].lower())
        except KeyError:
            print ("Number out of range")

n = eval(input("Please enter a number between 1 and 9999 inclusive: "))
num2Word(n)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19504350/how-to-convert-numbers-to-words-in-python

Answer (score 1):

You only try-except once, meaning this will work for max 2 digits. Try doing it recursively. I could make you a working answer if you want one.
Instead of doing n2W[n%10].lower(), use recursive call to num2Word.

Answer (score 0):

Just plug in a number manually can you can see why there is an error

For example try n=111

`(n2W[n-n%10] , n2W[n%10].lower())`

`111%10=1`, so you have:

`n2W[110]` and `n2W[1]`

The `n2W[110]` is your key error, it just needs to recurse back through your function.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this solution in which we iterate over the number digits from left to right, map `value` to text in each iteration and then abandon the most significant digit.

```
def num2Word(n):
    try:
        word = ''
        c = 1000
        while n:
            value = (n//c)*c if n > c else None
            n %= c
            c /= 10
            if value is not None:
                word += '%s ' % n2W[value] 
    except KeyError:
        print ("Number out of range")
    return word 

 n = eval(input("Please enter a number between 1 and 9999 inclusive: "))
 print num2Word(n)
```

For example, for n = 1234 we will have four iterations with `value` equals to:

`value` = 1000
`value` = 200
`value` = 30
`value` = 4

Comment: @dprogram please consider accepting the answer if it was helpful for you by clicking the check-mark.

Answer (score -1):

You're best using the `num2words` library, which you can install using:

```
pip install num2words
```

You can then do this:

```
import num2words
num2words.num2words(42) # forty-two
```

Comment: This would be helpful as a comment, but the OP was wondering why his code wasn't working.  Your answer doesn't tell him.

Comment: Since this looks very much like a home work question I doubt OP's professor/teacher would accept something like this. Regardless the OP isn't asking for a library to solve their problem, they asking for help fixing their existing code.

Comment: I agree, but I'll leave this answer here for any future searchers.

Answer (score -1):

you can use **inflect** module to convert integer value into words.

```
import inflect 
i=inflect.engine()
x = i.number_to_words(49)
print(x)
```

output will be  : 'forty-nine'

Comment: This would be helpful as a comment, but the OP was wondering why his code wasn't working. Your answer doesn't tell him.