# Function for converting numeric value into word

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

Is there any function in progress for converting a numeric value into word or there is another way of doing it?
For ex- 1234 -> one thousand two hundred thirty four.

Comment: See this: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/convert-numbers-into-words-a0d166fb-e1ea-4090-95c8-69442cd55d98

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19504350/how-to-convert-numbers-to-words-in-python

Answer (score 2):

This will (not too much tests done) up to 9999. After that you will have to expand it to work.

```
DEFINE VARIABLE cNum2Words     AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO EXTENT 20 INITIAL ["zero","one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine","ten","eleven","twelve","thirteen","fourteen","fifteen","sixteen","seventeen","eigteen","nineteen"].
DEFINE VARIABLE cTens          AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO EXTENT 10 INITIAL ["","twenty","thirty","fourty","fifty","sixty","seventy","eighty","ninety"].
DEFINE VARIABLE cPostfix       AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO EXTENT 10 INITIAL ["","","hundred","thousand","hundredthousand","million"].

FUNCTION num2word RETURN CHARACTER (INPUT piNum AS INTEGER):

    RETURN cNum2Words[piNum + 1].

END.

FUNCTION num2words RETURNS CHARACTER (INPUT piNum AS INTEGER):

    DEFINE VARIABLE iStep   AS INTEGER NO-UNDO.
    DEFINE VARIABLE cReturn AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
    DEFINE VARIABLE iPos    AS INTEGER NO-UNDO.          

    IF piNum >= 0 AND piNum <= 19 THEN 
        RETURN num2Word(piNum).
    ELSE DO:

        DO iStep = LENGTH(STRING(piNum)) TO 1 BY -1:  

            iPos = iPos + 1.

            IF iStep = 1 THEN DO:
                cReturn = cReturn + " " +  num2word(INTEGER(SUBSTRING(STRING(piNum), iPos, 1))).
            END.
            ELSE IF iStep = 2 THEN DO:
                cReturn =  cReturn + " " + cTens[INTEGER(SUBSTRING(STRING(piNum), iPos, 1))].
            END.
            ELSE IF iStep > 2 AND iStep <= 6 THEN DO:
                cReturn = cReturn + " " + num2word(INTEGER(SUBSTRING(STRING(piNum), iPos, 1))) + " " + cPostfix[iStep]. 
            END.

        END.                
    END.
    RETURN creturn.

END.

MESSAGE  num2words(9999) VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX .
```

Answer (score 2):

I dug this out of a (very) dusty corner and updated it a bit:

```
/* num2words.p
 *
 * convert integers to words...
 *
 * original: june 23, 1988
 * upgraded: june 01, 2020  (changed to a function with parameter passing rather than shared variables, added int64)
 *
 */

function num2words returns character( number as int64 ):

  define variable spelled as character no-undo.

  define variable i   as integer no-undo.
  define variable buf as character no-undo.
  define variable tmp as character no-undo.
  define variable mag as integer extent 3 no-undo.

  define variable ones  as character extent 10 initial [ "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "" ] no-undo.
  define variable teens as character extent 10 initial [ "Ten", "Eleven", "Twelve", "Thirteen", "Fourteen", "Fifteen", "Sixteen", "Seventeen", "Eighteen", "Nineteen" ] no-undo.
  define variable tens  as character extent 10 initial [ "", "Twenty", "Thirty", "Forty", "Fifty", "Sixty", "Seventy", "Eighty", "Ninety", "" ] no-undo.
  define variable order as character extent  5 initial [ "Trillion", "Billion", "Million", "Thousand", "" ] no-undo.

  tmp = string( number, "999999999999999" ).
  spelled = "".
  if number = 0 then
    do:
      spelled = "Zero".
      return spelled.
    end.

  i = 0.
  do while i < 5:

    buf = substring( tmp, (( i * 3 ) + 1 ), 3 ).

    mag[1] = integer( substring( buf, 3, 1 )).
    mag[2] = integer( substring( buf, 2, 1 )).
    mag[3] = integer( substring( buf, 1, 1 )).

    if mag[3] > 0 then                spelled = spelled + ones[mag[3]] + " " + "Hundred" + " ".
    if mag[2] > 1 and mag[1] = 0 then spelled = spelled + tens[mag[2]] + " ".
    if mag[2] > 1 and mag[1] > 0 then spelled = spelled + tens[mag[2]] + " " + ones[mag[1]] + " ".
    if mag[2] = 1 then                spelled = spelled + teens[mag[1] + 1] + " ".
    if mag[2] = 0 and mag[1] > 0 then spelled = spelled + ones[mag[1]] + " ".

    i = i + 1.

    if /* spelled <> "" and */
       ( mag[1] <> 0 or mag[2] <> 0 or mag[3] <> 0 )           /* bug fix */
     then spelled = spelled + order[i] + " ".

  end.

  return trim( spelled ).

end.

display ( num2words( 1234567890123 ) + "." )format "x(150)".
```

Comment: Well... so 10,000,000 is 10 million thousand? Pesky unit tests. https://abldojo.services.progress.com:443/#/?shareId=5ed9592e4b1a0f40c34b8c5b

Comment: well that's embarrassing :(

Comment: To make it even better - that bug is also in the unmodernized code and I suspect that it might also be in the production systems that still use it.

Comment: Bug fix added. The original bug was indeed found and fixed in 1994. It lived for 6 years before being squashed. I guess the fact that it was spotted in less than a week here shows the power of the modern internet :)

Answer (score 0):

Not built in, no. You will probably have to write your own.