# creating a list with numbers and a second list with numbers in string form with range [0-9]

Tags: python, list

i want to create a list from an existing list with numbers from 0-9, but the new list has the numbers in string form, for example if user input are numbers 2,3,4,5 the new list will print ["two,"three,"four","five], any suggestions to improve my code?

```
list1 = [0,1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
list2 = ["zero","one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine"]
list3 = []

num = int(input("give me desired range\n"))
for i in range(num):
 number = int(input("give me desired numbers\n"))
  if number == list1[i]:
    if number == list2[i]:
        list3 = list2[i]


 print(list3)
```

Comment: `improve my code` ? It actually don't works

Comment: Check this out may be this can help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19504350/how-to-convert-numbers-to-words-without-using-num2word-library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each number, just access the `list2` by index

```
list2 = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten"]
list3 = []

num = int(input("How many numbers do you want to type: "))
for i in range(num):
    number = int(input("Give a number to convert: "))
    list3.append(list2[number - 1])
```

Out

```
How many numbers do you want to type: 3
Give a number to convert: 1
Give a number to convert: 5
Give a number to convert: 9
['one', 'five', 'nine']
```

---

Or you can pair your 2 lists, then access `pairs` by key

```
pairs = dict(zip(list1, list2))
num = int(input("How many numbers do you want to type: "))
for i in range(num):
    number = int(input("Give a number to convert: "))
    list3.append(pairs[number])
```

Comment: If this solves your question, you can accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't work. I don't know what those `if`s are for. you can just get the number from input and add use it as index for `list2`. and you don't need `list1`.

```
list2 = ["zero","one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine"]
list3 = []

num = int(input("give me desired range\n"))
for i in range(num):
    number = int(input("give me desired numbers\n"))
    list3.append(list2[number])
print(list3)
```

If you need this for larger numbers, instead of typing numbers yourself you can use a package named [Inflect](https://pypi.org/project/inflect/). It has a method for turning numbers into english text:

```
import inflect
e = inflect.engine()
e.number_to_words(8)
```

output:

```
'eight'
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
list1 = ["zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten"]
list2 = []

numbers = input("Input desired numbers: ")
numbers = numbers.split(", ")
for number in numbers:
    list2.append(list1[int(number)])

print(list2)
```

Here you go

Comment: You don't need to specify the amount of numbers to be inputted.
Just input like so:
Input desired numbers: 1, 4, 9
["one", "four", "nine"]