# python code for give a number from 0 to 1000 from the input and prints it in words?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

i would like to create a program that reads a number from zero to 1000 from the **input** ( user)  and prints its word equivalent in [Indian numbering system.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_numbering_system)

> Input: 438237764 from user
>
> Output: forty three crore eighty two lakh
> thirty seven thousand seven hundred and
> sixty four

i found something like that but it's not for number giving:

```
one = [ "", "one ", "two ", "three ", "four ",
    "five ", "six ", "seven ", "eight ",
    "nine ", "ten ", "eleven ", "twelve ",
    "thirteen ", "fourteen ", "fifteen ",
    "sixteen ", "seventeen ", "eighteen ",
    "nineteen "];
``ten = [ "", "", "twenty ", "thirty ", "forty ",
        "fifty ", "sixty ", "seventy ", "eighty ",
        "ninety "];



# n is 1- or 2-digit number
def numToWords(n, s):
 
    str = "";
     
    # if n is more than 19, divide it
    if (n > 19):
        str += ten[n // 10] + one[n % 10];
    else:
        str += one[n];
 
    # if n is non-zero
    if (n):
        str += s;
 
    return str;
 
# Function to print a given number in words
def convertToWords(n):
 
    # stores word representation of given
    # number n
    out = "";
 
    # handles digits at ten millions and
    # hundred millions places (if any)
    out += numToWords((n // 10000000),
                            "crore ");
 
    # handles digits at hundred thousands
    # and one millions places (if any)
    out += numToWords(((n // 100000) % 100),
                                   "lakh ");
 
    # handles digits at thousands and tens
    # thousands places (if any)
    out += numToWords(((n // 1000) % 100),
                             "thousand ");
 
    # handles digit at hundreds places (if any)
    out += numToWords(((n // 100) % 10),
                            "hundred ");
 
    if (n > 100 and n % 100):
        out += "and ";
 
    # handles digits at ones and tens
    # places (if any)
    out += numToWords((n % 100), "");
 
    return out;
 
# Driver code
 
# long handles upto 9 digit no
# change to unsigned long long
# int to handle more digit number
n = 438237764;
 
# convert given number in words
print(convertToWords(n));
```

Comment: This question was answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19504350/how-to-convert-numbers-to-words-without-using-num2word-library

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> from num2words import num2words
>>> num2words(4553)
'four thousand, five hundred and fifty-three'
```

**Check the below link for more**

https://pypi.org/project/num2words/